# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined | Finding the shortest word in a string | Codewars Challenge

Tags: javascript

## **I am currently trying to create a function that looks for the shortest word in a string of words.**

**Problem: I am getting the following error**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at findShort
    at Test.describe._
    at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:152:11
    at Promise._execute
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor
    at new Promise
    at Object.describe
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:24:10
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:28:5
    at Object.handleError

**Here is my code**

```js
findShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones");

function findShort(s){

  let array = s.split(" ");
  let shortestWord = array[0];
  
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let str = array[i + 1];
    
    if (shortestWord.length > str.length) {
      shortestWord = str.length;
    }
    
  }
  
  return shortestWord;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

- The line `let str = array[i + 1]` is going to result in `undefined` on the last run of your loop. That's because on the last run, `i` is one less than the array length, so `i + 1` is therefore out of the array bounds. To compensate for that, consider changing the loop condition to `i < array.length - 1`.
- Second, you are assigning the word length to the `shortestWord` variable, where I think you meant to assign the word itself to that.

Taking those two changes into account, you could modify your code like so:

```js
function findShort(s) {

  let array = s.split(" ");
  let shortestWord = array[0];
  
  for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { // -1 here to compensate for the +1 on the next line.
    let str = array[i + 1];
    
    if (shortestWord.length > str.length) {
      shortestWord = str; // Just assign the word itself to this variable, not the length of it.
    }
    
  }
  
  return shortestWord;
}

const result = findShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks You, great explanation on my mistakes and how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a more concise way of doing what you're looking for:

```js
console.log(findShort("turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones"));

function findShort(s){
  let input = s;
  let array = input.split(" ");
  
  var shortest = array.reduce((shortestWord, currentWord) => {
    return currentWord.length < shortestWord.length ? currentWord : shortestWord;
  }, array[0]);
  return shortest;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/02z5oyh1/

Comment: This is a very efficient way to do it, I am kind of new to programming but I will keep in mind the way you solved the problem.